# How to generate a ECDH key value pair with a public key from Server in IOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, public-key-encryption, ecdh

I have tried to generate a key value pair with ECDH, I have succeeded in generating a two key value pairs. With two pairs I have generated a shared secret and it works fine. But when I try to create a shared secret with a public key from the server, I couldn't do it. The public key from the server is in hex Format. I cannot convert the hex value to a public key (secKey).

Code to generate a two key value pairs and two shared secret:

```
var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        let keyPairAttr:[String : Any] = [kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 256,
                                          SecKeyKeyExchangeParameter.requestedSize.rawValue as String: 32,
                                          kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
                                          kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
                                          kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String: [kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false],
                                          kSecPublicKeyAttrs as String:[kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false]]
        let algorithm:SecKeyAlgorithm = SecKeyAlgorithm.ecdhKeyExchangeStandardX963SHA256 //ecdhKeyExchangeStandardX963SHA256

        do {
            guard let privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(keyPairAttr as CFDictionary, &error) else {
                throw error!.takeRetainedValue() as Error
            }
            let publicKey = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(privateKey)

 guard let privateKey2 = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(keyPairAttr as CFDictionary, &error) else {
                throw error!.takeRetainedValue() as Error
            }
let publicKey2 = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(privateKey2)
           

let shared:CFData? = SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult(privateKey, algorithm, publicKey2!, keyPairAttr as CFDictionary, &error)
            let sharedData:Data = shared! as Data
            print("shared Secret key",sharedData.base64EncodedString())

            let shared2:CFData? = SecKeyCopyKeyExchangeResult(privateKey2, algorithm, publicKey!, keyPairAttr as CFDictionary, &error)
            let sharedData2:Data = shared2! as Data
            print("shared Secret key 2",sharedData2.base64EncodedString())

if sharedData.base64EncodedString() == sharedData2.base64EncodedString() {  
                let secretKey = sharedData.base64EncodedString()
                print("SEC KEY MATCHES",secretKey)
}
```

The above code works as I have created two key value pairs myself. But I couldn't create it with public key from server.
I need to know how to create a shared secret with public key from server which is in hex format.

Answer (score 0):

kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 256
256 should be 384